# Issues with Datadog Trace IDs in Kotlin Applications, Especially with Coroutine Support and Splunk Logging

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, splunk, datadog

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm encountering challenges with Datadog trace IDs in applications written in Kotlin, specifically related to coroutine support and logging to Splunk. I'm curious if anyone else has faced similar issues.

This may be related to the discussion on GitHub: [DataDog/dd-trace-java issue #931](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-java/issues/931).

If you've experienced or resolved similar problems, could you please share your insights or solutions? Any guidance on how to handle Datadog trace IDs in Kotlin applications, especially with regards to coroutines and Splunk logging, would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I have tried logging Datadog Trace ID as follows:

Implemented logging of Datadog trace ID using

`CorrelationIdentifier.getTraceIdKey() to CorrelationIdentifier.getTraceId()`

Verified that the trace ID is being retrieved correctly within the code.

And I also added the following to the YAML configuration file

`DD_INTEGRATION_KOTLIN_COROUTINE_EXPERIMENTAL_ENABLED: true`

I expected this configuration change to improve Datadog trace ID handling in a Kotlin coroutine environment however I still see distinct requests sharing the same datadog trace id.

I am seeking insights from the community on any additional considerations, best practices, or potential solutions for ensuring reliable Datadog trace ID handling in a complex Kotlin microservices environment.